# how to handle eth and wei together in ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, ethereumjs, javascript-vm

suppose I have the function to send multiple amount's at once from an array but each value is uncertain or unknown:

```
let value = [0,0.87,9.5,0.342,0.66,8]
let valueInWei;
for(let i =0;i<value.length;i++){
   valueInWei += ethers.Utils.parseUnits(value[i])//I'm stuck here someone helps me guide me to the right method for achieving this
}
let valueInWei;
let valueInEth =  ;
```

now what I want to do is handle each amount converted into wei and then convert that wei into eth and pass it to a trx object in ether's js